# How to disable CS1514 in Visual Studio 2022 preview

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'd like to know if there is a way yet to disable the CS1514 Error Warning for Visual Studio 2022 Preview.

Beginning with C#10.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/namespaces) namespaces can be declared like this:

```
namespace SampleNamespace;
```

without braces but visual studio 2022 preview still shows this as an error.
I understand that this is a new feature but is there a way to disable the warning for this, like #pragma warning disable or something like that?

Comment: Check your `LangVersion` property in your csproj.

Comment: You don't tend to disable warnings at the *visual studio installation level*. There are project level settings for controlling warnings and errors.

Comment: I did that already and tried to increase it, but it didn't remove the error warning

Comment: LangVersion 7-10 are "all" not removing the CS1514 and CS1513 errors for me. As far as i know its only possible to use LangVersion 7 yet.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so, my projects works even though i get these errors - i can start my blazor project with dotnet watch run instead of the visual studio debugger. The thing is i'm using a template from microsoft (dotnet new blazorwasm --pwa --hosted) - so i would expect Visual Studio to be able to run this template as is it from Microsoft

Comment: Which version are you using? Have you tried the *latest* version? Don't change the language version to anything less than 10 - file namespaces are a C# 10 feature. The [latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview) is VS 2022 17.0 RC

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos using Version 17.0.0 Preview 1.1

Comment: I see there are newer versions, thanks @PanagiotisKanavos i'll try the latest RC

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos everything works fine now on the newest RC Version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an older Version of 2022 Preview.
I'm now using the
[latest](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview) RC Version.
This resolved this problem for me, thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for the hint.